# How to center the middle term with two inequalities in LaTeX?

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, alignment, center

Can someone please help me with centering the middle term here?

```
\begin{align*}
    \Big|f(x)-T^{(3)}(x,0)\Big| &\leq \frac{|f^{(4)}(\xi)}{4!} x^4 &&\leq \frac{x^4}{4!} \\
    x-\frac{x^3}{3!}-\frac{x^4}{4!} &\leq \sin x &&\leq x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!} \\
    -\frac{x^3}{3!}-\frac{x^4}{4!} &\leq \sin x - x &&\leq -\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!} \\
    -\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{x}{4!} &\leq \frac{\sin x - x}{x^3} &&\leq -\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{x}{4!} 
\end{align*}
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. Could you please add a complete code starting from the beginning with the documentclass with all the packages. In synthesis a compilable code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with an `array`.

I show two realizations, in the second one the top row is globally centered with respect to the derivations below. Take your pick, I'd prefer the latter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.4}
\begin{array}{
  >{\displaystyle}r 
  >{{}}c<{{}}
  >{\displaystyle}c
  >{{}}c<{{}}
  >{\displaystyle}l
}
\bigl|f(x)-T^{(3)}(x,0)\bigr|   &\leq& \frac{|f^{(4)}(\xi)|}{4!}x^4 &\leq& \frac{x^4}{4!} \\
x-\frac{x^3}{3!}-\frac{x^4}{4!} &\leq& \sin x                       &\leq& x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!} \\
-\frac{x^3}{3!}-\frac{x^4}{4!}  &\leq& \sin x - x                   &\leq& -\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!} \\
-\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{x}{4!}      &\leq& \frac{\sin x - x}{x^3}       &\leq& -\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{x}{4!} 
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\begin{gather*}
  \bigl|f(x)-T^{(3)}(x,0)\bigr|\leq \frac{|f^{(4)}(\xi)|}{4!}x^4 \leq \frac{x^4}{4!}
\\
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.4}
\begin{array}{
  >{\displaystyle}r 
  >{{}}c<{{}}
  >{\displaystyle}c
  >{{}}c<{{}}
  >{\displaystyle}l
}
x-\frac{x^3}{3!}-\frac{x^4}{4!} &\leq& \sin x                 &\leq& x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!} \\
-\frac{x^3}{3!}-\frac{x^4}{4!}  &\leq& \sin x - x             &\leq& -\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!} \\
-\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{x}{4!}      &\leq& \frac{\sin x - x}{x^3} &\leq& -\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{x}{4!} 
\end{array}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

With `>{\displaystyle}r` we specify a right aligned column with math set in displaystyle; similarly for `c` and `l`.

With `>{{}}c<{{}}` we set a centered column where the entry is surrounded by `{}...{}`, so as to trigger the automatic spacing around a relation symbol.

The intercolumn space is set to zero, so just those automatically inserted spaces will govern the table. The parameter `\arraystretch` is set to a rather large value in order to accommodate the fractions.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Really appreciate it.